# how do i configure smtp setting with mail function?

Tags: php, email, smtp, sendmail

how do i configure smtp setting with mail function smtp is required because of web hosting doesn't allow to sending email without smtp setting due to security reason.

```
warning error: mail() has been disabled for security reasons
```

now how can i configure smtp setting with this mail function ()?

```
<?php 
if(isset($_REQUEST['confirm'])){
$your_email = 'non-reply@test.com'; //CHANGE TO YOUR SETTINGS
$domain = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; //YOUR DOMAIN AND EXTENSION
$to = $email;
$subject = 'Demo Your Order';
$message = 'test1234';
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";  
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";  
$headers .= "From: Demo.Pk<'.$your_email.'@'.$domain.'>\r\n" .  
//"Reply-To: $from \r\n" .  
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion(); 

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

?>

Comment: No amount of smtp configuration is going to re-enable `mail()` if it's been disabled by your host. Get a new host.

Comment: @mikeb web hosting technical said to me send email through smtp setting?

Comment: Do not use `mail()` directly for anything, ever. Take a look at [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that mail is disable or does not have proper setting in your PHP.ini. I think, you can still send email using SMTP set to some other SMTP server like gmail. Please check below code, it might help you in solving this issue. Below code is using Mail.php frm PEAR

```
<?php

       require_once "Mail.php";

        $from = "<me@gmail.com>";
        $to = "<you@gmail.com>";
        $subject = "Hi!";
        $body = "Hi,\n\nHope this helps?";

        $host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
        $port = "465";
        $username = "me@gmail.com";  //<> give errors
        $password = "mypassword";

        $headers = array ('From' => $from,
          'To' => $to,
          'Subject' => $subject);
        $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
          array ('host' => $host,
            'port' => $port,
            'auth' => true,
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password));

        $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

        if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
          echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
         } else {
          echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
         }

    ?>
```

You can also use some other Mail libraries like PHPMailer

Comment: amit i have tried this code but problem is that showing error on the $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',

Comment: You need to include Mail Pear library in your library path, please download PEAR::Mail and include PEAR library in your include path